# How to run retrofit in retrofit?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm making cryptocurrency information viewer using Retrofit. Everything is okay, but have a problem.

One exchange demands me execute retrofit twice.

https://api.upbit.com/v1/market/all

https://api.upbit.com/v1/ticker?markets=KRW-BTC,KRW-ETH,KRW-BTG,KRW-BSV,KRW-ETC ..., KRW-(Some cryptocurrency)

Base url is "https://api.upbit.com/v1/". And I have to get 'markets' from first api, and get cryptocurrency's information by using 'markets' as query value.

But there are problem. I thought first and second execution. Get markets from first execution, and get infomations by using markets. But Retrofit basically runs asynchronously, So usually skip first execution and there are no markets in second executions. (markets = "")

How can I run Retrofit in Retrofit? Did I approach wrong? Or there are solution for this problem?

This is Retrofit parts in my code.

```
var markets = ""
val publishSubject: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()
init {
    publishSubject.subscribe {
        markets = it
    }
}

fun getData(exchange: String) {
    // var markets = "Basic"
    val url = when(exchange) {
        coinone -> "https://api.coinone.co.kr/"
        bithumb -> "https://api.bithumb.com/"
        upbit -> {
            getMarketsUpbit()
            "https://api.upbit.com/v1/"
        }
        else -> "https://api-cloud.huobi.co.kr/"
    }

    val parser = DataParser()

    val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitService::class.java)

    val call: retrofit2.Call<Any> =
        when (exchange) {
                coinone ->
                    builder.getTickersCoinone("all")
                bithumb ->
                    builder.getTickersBithumb()
                upbit ->
                    builder.getTickersUpbit(markets)
                else ->
                    builder.getTickersHuobi()
            }

    call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Any> {
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<Any>, response: retrofit2.Response<Any>) {
            coinInfos.value = parser.getParsedData(
                    if (exchange != "upbit") exchange
                    else markets
                ,
                    response.body().toString()
            )
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
            println("Retrofit process is failed.")
        }
    })
}


private fun getMarketsUpbit() {
    val parser = DataParser()
    var markets = ""

    val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.upbit.com/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitService::class.java)

    val call: retrofit2.Call<Any> = builder.getMarketsUpbit()

    call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Any> {
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<Any>, response: retrofit2.Response<Any>) {
            publishSubject.onNext(parser.parseUpbitMarkets(response.body().toString()))
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
            println("Retrofit process is failed.")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Retrofit has built in coroutine support. I suggest migrating to them so you can seamlessly chain the calls.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I solved this by using call.execute()!